# SSIS hangs all the time

Tags: ssis-2012

SSIS hangs and I am unable to open the solution. In the lower left corner there is a message "Testing Connectivity". SSIS does not respond to any command, it does not let me access the package or change any setting.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows explorer, Go to the folder with the solution and package that you cannot open

Open the user preferences file , that is the file with the extension .user

Open the file in a text editor and find the  setting for OfflineMode

Change the value to true, it should look like this: "OfflineMode > true< / OfflineMode>" (wihtout the spaces)